# Setting a count of localStorage keys which start with a unique word using jQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, count, local-storage

Please help! I set localStorage items like: you-title, you-firstname, partner-title, partner-firstname, and I would like to count how many of each prefix have been set and set the count with the prefix as the key. I can get as far as getting the prefix and counting single prefixes:

```
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var prefix = key.split('-')[0];

    if (prefix === 'you') {
            j++;
            localStorage.setItem(prefix, j);
   }
}
```

But I have rather a lot of different prefixes so I don't want to hard code them this way.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Ben.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you could create an object with the key/value pairs as the prefix and the count. This way you don't need to know what the key is as it's all set at runtime:

```
var counterObj = {};
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){
  var prefix = key.split('-')[0];
  counterObj[prefix] = ++counterObj[prefix] || 1;
});

console.log(counterObj);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/e0n8b1re/)

Note I had to put the example in a jsFiddle as SO snippets restrict access to localStorage.